# Global variable within akka actor system in Scala

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I currently use an akka Actor system in my Scala code. I have a parent actor and a child actor. What i want to do is initiate a List at the parent actor and let the child actor:

i)Generate new elements and send them to parent actor who will attach them to the list.
ii)Have access at the list elements at anytime.

How can i achieve the second(ii) part?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I managed to find a solution.

If you create a variable inside the parent Actor and pass it as a construction parameter to the child Actor , every alteration in this variable is visible if you do not replace it. I will explain with a correct example following a false example.

```
class ParentActor(/*constructors here*/) extends Actor{
   val list =ListBuffer[Int](1,2)
   child = new ChildActor(list //+other constructors)

   list=ListBuffer[Int](1,2,3) // **wrong** child will see list=List(1,2)
   list+=3         // **right**  child will see list=List(1,2,3) as wanted
```

}

```
class ChildActor(list : ListBuffer[Int] /*++ otherconstructors here*/) extends Actor{

       list=ListBuffer[Int](1,2,3,4) // **wrong** parent will see list=List(1,2,3)
       list+=4           // **right**  child will see list=List(1,2,3,4) as wanted
```

}

Comment: This solution is an Akka anti-pattern and is not recommendable. First of all, note that `ListBuffer` is not a thread-safe collection. Second, even choosing a thread-safe collection would violate location transparency - as serialization would be impossible. Further reading here http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2016/08/02/akka-anti-patterns-shared-mutable-state/

Answer (score 4):

You ***must*** use message passing.  Sharing any kind of mutable state between two actors violates every guarantee offered by Akka.

Alternatively, you could share an *Agent* between your child and parent actors, which would linearize updates to the list while allow synchronous reads.

Comment: I changed myquestion to be more representative of what i wish to do:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247523/how-to-periodically-check-an-actor-mailbox-and-alter-variables-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a specific message to which the Parent can reply disclosing its internal status. See an example below:

```
  import scala.collection.immutable.Queue

  class Parent extends Actor {
    import Parent._

    // TODO: start children here

    override def receive: Receive = receiveElements(Queue.empty[Element])

    def receiveElements(acc: Queue[Element]): Receive = {
      case e@Element => context.become(receiveElements(acc :+ e))
      case GetElements => sender ! acc
    }
  }

  object Parent {
    case class Element(s: String)
    case object GetElements
  }
```

Note that the same behaviour is achievable by keeping a `var queue` internal to the Parent instead of using `context.become`+recursion.

Also, not designing a way for the queue to be flushed can potentially lead to OOME.

Comment: The problem is that i wish to have access to this List while running. I want my child actor to receive a "start" message, run a function and inside thiw function have access to the List. I do not want to wait for the first message to be processed and then handle a second message.

Comment: Simply put: not possible.  This violates every tenet of Akka.

Comment: Question redefined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247523/how-to-periodically-check-an-actor-mailbox-and-alter-variables-in-scala