# How to periodically check an actor mailbox and alter variables in scala

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am using akka actors in Scala. I would like to know if there is a way to have an actor, which while processing a message received can periodically check its mailbox for other messages and following this messages can alter its variables.

A scheme like:

```
class Actor1 (constructors){

    def receive={
       case "go" => run()       //the actor starts
       case "alter variables"  // a new message is stashed in mailbox
    }

    def run={
       //do stuff
       check(mailbox) //while the porocessing of the "go" message 
                     // is not finished
       if ( "alter variables" in mailbox) {
          change a variable value
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that, but I think it would break the design patterns that Akka tries to enforce, so I would discourage doing it.  You might be able to rig something up that's similar by implementing your own queue that you put the messages in, and have some other mechanism that makes it check that queue.

Comment: This is not possible.  Actors process *one message at a time*.  This is how they guarantee safe mutable state in a concurrent environment.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing says you can't move a long running task into a different thread, using a Future, inside an actor. Your actor would continue to respond to messages in the mailbox, while another thread chugs away on your processing. You can set up your callbacks on the future, and let the task finish normally.

Comment: Note that modifying an actor's state from a callback is very, very dangerous and should never ben done.

Comment: I don't want to use Futures because i have already tried them and as a result the code I am currently writing is slower than its single-core version. I want to either access my mailbox at anytime or access a variable from two different actors in the same system.

Comment: @user1834705 That is not possible.